# synchronize between publisher and subscriber

Tags: ros

I am working on test program which subscribes to one topic published by main program. There is only single message on this topic published by main program. Now it might happen that my subscriber is not alive when publisher is publishing a message and it will get lost. One way to avoid it is put while inside main program till numsubcribers are not zero. but I cannot put while inside my main program. How do i achieve it?

Comment: Please add the programming language and a minimal example to your question

Answer (score 1):

So since you say that there is only a single message send by the main program, this is probably a job for the `latch` argument when you allocate the publisher:

> latch [optional]
>
> Enables "latching" on a connection. When a connection is latched, the last message published is saved and automatically sent to any future subscribers that connect. This is useful for slow-changing to static data like a map. Note that if there are multiple publishers on the same topic, instantiated in the same node, then only the last published message from that node will be sent, as opposed to the last published message from each publisher on that single topic.

Just give your publisher the argument as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Publisher_Options), and ROS handles the message passing to your subscriber when it comes up:

```
...
bool latch = true;
ros::Publisher advertise(topic, latch)
...
```